# calling web service using jquery when web service created with servicestack

Tags: jquery, web-services, servicestack

I have a web service created using ServiceStack. I am trying to consume in asp.net using javascript / jquery.

Below code is what i tried.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:55037/Json/syncreply/GetSourceData?SourceID=1&Active=true",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        //data: "{SourceID: 1, Active: true }",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function(msg) {
            debugger
            alert(msg)
        },
        error: function(e) {
            alert(e.statusText);
        }
    });
});
```

Seems its not reaching the web service and It returns an error message "No Transport".

Comment: cross-site HTTP Request ?

Comment: Since its localhost i doubt its a CORS issue, but if you are running chrome open the bottom panel and it'll have a text in red that says no cross domain requests are allowed.

Comment: You don't usually need the '/Json/syncreply/' in your url. Can you show your Route configuration as well as your Service and Request classes? Also, are you hosting ServiceStack on a 'Custom Path' like '/api/'?

Comment: @paaschpa agreed with you... Url is not looking good. Even if Json is there it will be after query string tag I guess as by default service stack api provide every requested type. We don't need to explicitly tell that.